# Check the response of an API for correctness

Tags: javascript

I expecting the response of an API to be a array of objects like this:

```
[
    {
        "code": "X",
        "name": "Product A",
        "pricings": []
    },
    {
        "code": "Y",
        "name": "Product B",
        "pricings": []
    },
    {
        "code": "Z",
        "name": "Product C",
        "pricings": []
    }
]
```

I want to check if the response actually looks like this, to sort out error's.

I did the following:

```
function checkResponseApi(response, mustHave) {     
    if(Array.isArray(response)) {

        if(response.length === 0) {
            return false;
        }

        var success = response.every(obj => {
            var keys = Object.keys(obj);
            var output = mustHave.map(el => keys.includes(el));

            return output.indexOf(false) === -1;
        })

        return success;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}



if (checkResponseApi(arr, ["code", "name", "pricings"])) {
    // continue
} else {
    // handle error
}
```

Is this a valid solution? Maybe you can share some experience and provide another/better approach.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to code review where we review working code to provide suggestions on how the code can be improved. Code that has been replaced by comments such as `// continue` or `// handle error` makes the question off-topic because it is hypothetical. Code review requires the real code.

Comment: Thanks. I'm sorry I just included this to give the readers a context how the function is called. I remember this for the next time.

Comment: That context was good, but really more context was neede.

Comment: "Is this a valid solution?" Did you test it? Does it produce the expected result?

Comment: Of Course I test it. But you're right, my formulation was quite misleading. I just wanted to know how to improve the code. Thanks for your feedback @Mast I try to be more precisely next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Towards better performance and code organization

The list of required fields is better defined as `const` at top level:

```
const requiredFields = ["code", "name", "pricings"];
```

There are 2 negative outcomes that can be combined and checked at once:
1) if the `response` is not of `Array` type, 2) if it's empty array. The *Consolidate conditional expression* technique is applied.

```
if (!Array.isArray(resp) || !resp.length) {
    return false;
}
```

Instead of getting list of keys for each object in `response` array with `var keys = Object.keys(obj)` - the more efficient and faster way is to just apply `obj.hasOwnProperty(el)` to check if an object `obj` has required field `el` as a key.
All the rest "movements" in the initial approach are redundant and eliminated.

---

The final optimized approach:

```js
function checkResponseApi(resp, mustHave) {     
    if (!Array.isArray(resp) || !resp.length) {
     return false;
    }
    return resp.every(obj => {
        return mustHave.every(el => obj.hasOwnProperty(el))
    });
}

let arr = [
    {"code": "X", "name": "Product A", "pricings": []},
    {"code": "Y", "name": "Product B", "pricings": []},
    {"code": "Z", "name": "Product C", "pricings": []}
];
const requiredFields = ["code", "name", "pricings"];


if (checkResponseApi(arr, requiredFields)) {
    console.log('Ok')
} else {
    console.log('Bad response')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation RomanPerekhrest. One question left: is there a reason why the list of fields is better defined on top? :)

Comment: @Matthias, welcome. The list of fixed values is definitely better defined at once on top-level to make all callers easily refer to it. Otherwise, if it's dynamic list of fields - another question (addressed to you) would come out - by what rules you are building those "dynamic" lists?

Comment: These are the fields of the response that I definitely need in order to proceed with my app (Vue SPA). I simply defined them by looking what I need in order to get no error. Sometimes the API return some errors and I want to be able to track them so that I can stop the workflow, give the user a matching error message and of course log the errors. Btw unfortunaley I can't give you a upvoted, because I don't have enough reputation.